# Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. ggstatsplot package

Tags: r

Hi I'm trying to use the ggstatsplot package to make really nice-looking stats graphs, however when running the codes in the documentation: https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/
I get the constant following error:

Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `num.df` doesn't exist.

This is the code I'm running:

```
# for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
library(ggstatsplot)

# plot
ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(
  data = iris,
  x = Species,
  y = Sepal.Length,
  title = "Distribution of sepal length across Iris species"
)
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Restart R and try this on fresh R session.

Comment: As Ronak said, update all your libraries, refresh your R session, and then try again. This should work just fine.